# C++: working with multiple copies of std::cin?

Tags: c++, stdin, istream, noncopyable

I am writing a simple generalised parser combinator library. This means the library contains many small function objects, called parsers, which (when called) take a string as input and return a list of ParseResults as output, where a ParseResult is

`template <typename A>
using ParseResult = std::pair<A, std::string>`

The list is empty if the parser did not match, contains a single result if it did match, and certain parsers that might match in multiple (ambiguous) ways might return more results.

However, this means that right now, a whole lot of string copying is going on. Also, at the start, the finally constructed parser needs to be called with a string, so all of `std::cin` (or the coompete contents of a file) are copied to a string.

What seems like a better idea(since the parsers only ever look at the first (few) character(s) at the current front of the string) , is to keep track of where you are right now in the standard input stream. And I believe this is exactly what a `std::istream` is. However, istreams are not copyable. How can my problem be solved? 
Is there a way to return a copy of an istream that points to a few characters past where there original points to? Or is there another, cleaner way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know what references are in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be rephrased thus: *How do you represent unparsed part of the input in a way that avoids excessive copying and allows input streaming?*

The most flexible way is to represent it with an iterator. If you parsers do backtracking, it would need to be a `ForwardIterator`, if not, `InputIterator` is sufficient. This means you can then use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) over `std::cin`  or `std::ifstream`s directly, or parse from in-memory `std::strings` or `char` arrays. Streaming with backtracking is a bit more involved and would require you to write a buffering iterator adaptor that converts `InputIterator` like `std::istream_iterator` into a `ForwardIterator` or write an iterator directly wrapping `std::ifstream` and doing `.seekg()` when you need to backtrack.

Another option is to use C++17's  [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) which does not copy and has a nice, parsing-friendly interface. This does not solve streaming though, you'd still have to read entire file first.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Further research pointed out that `.seekg()` does not work properly for stdin, meaning that reading everything into memory (and then either using a `std::istringstream` or a `std::string_view` might very well be the best way to go.